# p:editor visible in chrome but not rendered properly in IE

Tags: primefaces, editor

The editor doesn't appears in my IE window while it works correctly in chrome

I have implemented p:layout and in the center layoutunit I am including the template.xhtml using ui:include which is enclosed in a

```
<h:form id="centercontentpanel">
```

Kindly guide me with what corrections needs to be done to make it visible in IE 8

Template.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:body>
<f:view> 
    <p:editor id="editor" value="#{editorBean.value}"/>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-top:10px">
        <p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="Submit" update="display" oncomplete="editordlg.show()"
                    icon="ui-icon-disk" />
        <p:commandButton id="clearButton" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="editor.clear()"
                    icon="ui-icon-close"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <p:dialog header="Content" widgetVar="editordlg" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" modal="true">
        <h:outputText id="display" value="#{editorBean.value}" escape="false" />
    </p:dialog>
</f:view>
</h:body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

<del>For all i know, the IE 8 doesn't support Primefaces Editor, still in IE 11.
Actually i can render it, but nothing works, not even the bold/italic/underline.</del>

<del>I think it's because the way IE process javascript... but i don't know much about technical issues.</del>

<del>(My tests were done on IE 11 and Primefaces 4.0, plain programming, didn't twitch anything)</del>

<del>Only for the RichText i'm using the HTML5 library [wysihtml5](http://xing.github.io/wysihtml5/) (GIT)</del>

EDIT:
I'm sorry, i just stumbled on the answear to my problem (Editing on IE), hope it fixes yours
Just add `contentType="text/html"` to the `<f:view>` like this `<f:view contentType="text/html">`
[Here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=19003#p19003) is the post from Optimus (Even though it's a rendering problem for chrome)